# Create a center node based on both polygon and line shapefile

Tags: polygon, algorithm, line

[image]

Sorry for cross posting. I want to develop a node layer from two other layers. One of the layers is a polygon contains a series of zones. Another layer is a line layer of roads. The nodes I want to create are basically, for each zone, centers of the roads instead of center of zone. For example, if a zone contains a park in the north with no roads there (zone 2), the node should be on the south side based on the roadway density in zone 2. Am I able to do that?

Comment: Where did you cross-post this?  Please **edit** the question to specify the GIS software you are using.  Generating a center of mass from the arcs selected in a relatively convex polygon doesn't appear to be all that difficult a challenge.